# Run into an error while trying to install Pandas in python using pip install

Tags: python, pandas

I'm just a beginner to learning python and currently following a course online to learn python still at the basic level. I wanted to install pandas module in my project and when i tried installing through the terminal in PyCharm I ran into an error that goes as follows, Can anyone help me get out of this problem.. Please..

***AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'***